# chrome mobile, jquery .ready() not firing when expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, mobile

I am working on an app for desktop/mobile. The jQuery `$(document).ready();` is definitely firing, which is why the app works. However, in the Chrome mobile browser, one particular function (to add some dynamic CSS to one element to place it correctly) is not firing correctly, and thus not updating the CSS when the page loads. The function fires normally and updates the CSS in the desktop browser. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function placeBook() {
    var h = $('#header').css('height');
    $('#button').css('height', h);
    $('#button').css('line-height', h);
  }
  placeBook();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    placeBook();
  });
});
```

The function `placeBook()` is not updating the CSS of the `#button` div on the first load of the page. However, the function fires *normally* on resize of the window, as specified in the code. It only fails on the mobile browser at the initial load of the page. See these SS's:

First load in desktop (FF responsive design view):

[image]

First load in mobile (Chrome):

[image: First load in mobile]

As you can see, the idea is that the book icon is to be centered vertically in the header. Of course, any help is appreciated.

Here is the HTML/CSS:

```
<div id='header'>
   <div id='button'>&#xe600;</div>
</div>


#header {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   font-size: 120%;
   text-align: center;
}
#button {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   padding: 0 1%;
}
```

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but instead of fixing it with JS try adding these styles to `#button` to vertical align: `display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;`.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem in Chrome: css is not being applied to dom, but when updated in console or styles are modified starts applying.

The problem was in sending incorrect mime type in headers of css files. This is chrome-specific peculiarity, because FF was more forgiving. Sending "text/css" fixed problem.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As per this answer:
[window.load doesn't fire always on chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825754/window-load-doesnt-fire-always-on-chrome)

It seems that it isn't safe to use `$(window).load();` on chrome, especially when it comes to DOM modifications. Instead use `$(document).ready();`! I've created a simple fiddle to confirm that load isn't always firing in chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/KvD6G/

Furthermore, instead of fixing this with javascript try doing it with css by applying the following styles:

```
#button {
  ...
  display:inline-block; 
  vertical-align:middle;
  ...
}
```

Comment: The problem persists whether I use `$(document).ready()` or `$(window).load()`.

Comment: Have you tried the css? And by the way try not to use `window load` at all in your code.

Comment: actually, your answer solved the problem on Chrome mobile, but created the same problem on desktop.

Comment: Yes, I have racked my brain with the CSS. The problem is this header is responsive, so it is using % in the padding to get the desired look based on window width. The `#button` is actually an `position:absolute` b/c I can't figure out an easy way to put it in the header, vertically centered without it bumping the header to the right.

Comment: And this one: `position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: -10px;` or whatever you need to pull it up to make up for the height. (margin top minus half the height in pixels). ?

Comment: I made a fiddle with a simulation of the javascript, and I'm kinda out of ideas untill I see some in depth css. Cause this one works for me in chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/T2pCq/5/

Comment: The margin-top changes based on the window width. I'll post some CSS. Check edit.

Comment: And have you tried doing these things with CSS media queries? They really make your life easier with these sorta things: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/. Furthermore, I created a fiddle that might solve the problem. I think it has to do with getting the height of the header 
http://jsfiddle.net/T2pCq/7/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to place your `placebook()` function in the global scope, outside of `doc ready` handler:

```
function placeBook() {
    var h = $('#header').css('height');
    $('#button').css({
       'height': h,
       'line-height': h
    });
}



$(window).load(function() {
  placeBook();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    placeBook();
  }).resize(); //<----invokes the resize function immediately
});
```

Although you have not mentioned your `doc ready handler`:

```
function placeBook() {
    var h = $('#header').css('height');
    $('#button').css({
       'height': h,
       'line-height': h
    });
}

$(function(){  //<------------------doc ready handler
  $(window).load(function() {
    placeBook();
    $(window).resize(function() {
       placeBook();
    }).resize(); //<----invokes the resize function immediately
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't think putting `$(window).load` inside the `ready` handler is gonna fix it in this case. Load will not be fired...

Comment: That's not the case whichever is inside `.load()` that would only be fired when window fully gets loaded and document ready func is just for telling that dom is ready for work.

Comment: Load will not be fired because often chrome is so fast that the window and document are already fully loaded before the javascript in question is executed. Thus causing the `$(window).load` event not to fire, since the `window load` has already occured before attaching the event handler. Order of execution is important here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825754/window-load-doesnt-fire-always-on-chrome

Comment: The way to get around this is by just using `$(function(){})` or `$(document).ready` because jQuery has a way to get around this problem by always triggering the `doc ready` event, even if the document was already fully loaded.

Comment: @Hless i have a demo for you, as you mentioned **order of execution** check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/T2pCq/

Comment: @Hless as you can see alert fired before load in the fiddle example, even though that is placed before alert.

Comment: @Hless another fiddle for demo _order of execution_ without load (_i commented that out here_): http://jsfiddle.net/T2pCq/1/

Comment: Not sure but placing the `placebook()` function in the global scope will might do the work.

Comment: To illustrate my point: http://jsfiddle.net/T2pCq/2/  VS http://jsfiddle.net/T2pCq/3/ . `document ready` is just safer. You never know how fast or slow the document will load for the user.

Comment: Exactly that's what i also meant. all events should be done in the `doc ready` handler unless you are delegating the event to the document.

Comment: Great, but your example still uses `window load` twice! Placing the function in the global scope could certainly fix things. But with `window load` still in place it's still not quite sure if that really is the problem. Placing functions on `document ready` should work since that event always get fired, as opposed to `window load`.

Comment: I have placed the function in the global scope and changed `$(window).load()` to `$(document).ready()`. Now, both desktop and mobile are broken on the initial page load.

Comment: So, no matter where I put the function `placeBook()`, `document ready` prevents it from working. I don't know why.

Comment: And you are sure that you are in no way dynamically adding `#header` and `#button` and that it is already present in your document when `document ready` gets executed?

Comment: @Hless, yes, I am sure. Those divs are hard-coded into the HTML.